# regular expression for numerated table of content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have template like this:

```
<h1>asd</h1>
...
<h1>asd</h1>
...
    <h2>asd</h2>
    ...
    <h2>asd</h2>
    ...
```

How to convert it to

```
<h1>1. asd</h1>
...
<h1>2. asd</h1>
...
    <h2>2.1. asd</h2>
    ...
    <h2>2.2. asd</h2>
    ...
```

with regular expressions in ruby 1.8.7 ?

Comment: I doubt if this can be done using regular expressions. Instead, I would use client-side javascript to do this on page load, by searching for those headings either using plain javascript's `document.getElementsByTagName` or using jQuery selectors.

Comment: @Vikdor I doubt that this cannot be done using regular expressions. Although, I agree with the latter part of your comment.

Comment: @sawa, I was not sure about the ruby extensions that would help do this using regular expressions. Your response below seems to be using one such extension/library.

Comment: It is standard in Ruby 1.9. It is not an extra library/extension. It is just a backport for Ruby 1.8. And I think I can do it without oniguruma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using oniguruma, which is installable on Ruby 1.8.7,

```
string =<<X
<h1>asd</h1>
...
<h1>asd</h1>
...
    <h2>asd</h2>
    ...
    <h2>asd</h2>
    ...
X

puts string.gsub(/(?<=<h1>).*?(?=<h1>|\z)/m).with_index{|s, i|
  s = s.gsub(/(?<=<h2>).*?(?=<h2>|\z)/m).with_index{|s, j|
    "#{i+1}.#{j+1}. #{s}"
  }
  "#{i+1}. #{s}"
}

#=>
# <h1>1. asd</h1>
# ...
# <h1>2. asd</h1>
# ...
#     <h2>2.1. asd</h2>
#     ...
#     <h2>2.2. asd</h2>
#     ...
```

Comment: but what if I have <h3> <h4> <h5> tags and so on? And I don't want to use third-party gems, if it possible

Comment: @sharpyfox My code is sufficient for what you gave in the question. If you have deeper hierarchy, just do the same. Note however, that html title tags ends at `<h6>`, so you don't have to worry for arbitrary depth. What do you mean third party gems?